# How to create present bottom view proper position for landscape mode using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, orientation

My scenario, I am trying to create present `bottom` sheet with `portrait` and `landscape` compatibility for `universal` application. Here, I made some `animation` for bottom view `present` and `dismiss` by using view `height` and static height calculation. Here during `portrait` mode everything working fine but if I change landscape mode I am getting unaligned bottom sheet `position`, It is showing top of the screen during `landscape` mode, some time not showing.

I am using below code,

```
    let cardHeight:CGFloat = 400
    let cardHandleAreaHeight:CGFloat = 0 

func setupCard() {
        visualEffectView = UIVisualEffectView()
        visualEffectView.frame = self.view.frame
        self.view.addSubview(visualEffectView)

        cardViewController = CardViewController(nibName:"CardViewController", bundle:nil)
        self.addChild(cardViewController)
        self.view.addSubview(cardViewController.view)

        cardViewController.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.frame.height - cardHandleAreaHeight, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: cardHeight)

        cardViewController.view.clipsToBounds = true

    }

func animateTransitionIfNeeded (state:CardState, duration:TimeInterval) {
        if runningAnimations.isEmpty {
            let frameAnimator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: duration, dampingRatio: 1) {
                switch state {
                case .expanded:
                    self.cardViewController.view.frame.origin.y = self.view.frame.height - self.cardHeight
                case .collapsed:
                    self.cardViewController.view.frame.origin.y = self.view.frame.height - self.cardHandleAreaHeight
                }
            }
}
```

[Sample image for portrait mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NpFUc.png)

[Sample image Landscape mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVkIR.png)